# How to Redirect to home tab after login Iphone App?

Tags: iphone, ios, authentication, tabbar

In my `AppDelegate.m`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    NSUserDefaults * defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    //Get uer ID from user defaults
    NSString *userid = [defaults objectForKey:@"UserId"];

    if([userid isEqualToString:@""]){

        login = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];
        [window addSubview:login.view];


    } else {

        [window addSubview:[rootTabBarController view]];

    }

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

and after login success i have this code

```
 NSUserDefaults * defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 [defaults setObject:serverOutput forKey:@"UserId"];
 //show tabbar app
 NewClassMoonAppDelegate * appsDelegate =[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
 [appsDelegate.window addSubview:[appsDelegate.rootTabBarController view]];
```

so the question is how can i redirect to specific tab **[Home tab FOR EXAMBLE]**?

Answer (score 1):

```
[appDelegate.rootTabBarController setSelectedIndex:GiveIndexOfTab]; // give index of home tab for ex. 0
```

Comment: Sorry i'm beginner in ios .. can you make more discuss .. when can i but this line on my above code

Comment: when you want to change the tabbar view programatically at that time just write this above line..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to jump to a specific tab without intercepting the tabBar, rather than the first default tab

use

```
[appsDelegate.rootTabBarController setSelectedIndex:2]; // 2 is a pseudo index i have assigned
```

Answer (score 0):

For tabbar controller,

SelectedIndex propery helps you to manage its behavior.

Use

```
setSelectedIndex:Index
```

method. It'll solve your purpose.

Thanks.